# Unable to check password length using regex in MVC4

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I am experimenting with the use of regex to check password complexity with MVC4 data annotations. I started with a simple regex to check for length, but the following does not work with strings of any length. What error am I making?

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.{8,})$", ErrorMessage = "Password not strong enough")]
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why regex ? just use `StringLength` attribute

Comment: @Selman22 - It appears like he is wanting to enforce some complexity requirements (upper, lower, numeric) as well as length and this is his starting point.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy, that is exactly right. I was trying to understand regexes before using them. For some reason, none of the resources I found online explained it as nicely as most of the posts here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the simple regex you were trying goes, you can just use:

```
^.{8,}$
```

You don't want the forward lookup (?=). See my description of why this is the case at the end.

For simple string length checking,  you can just use the StringLength length attribute if you are using asp.net 4.0:

```
[StringLength(8, MinimumLength=1)]
```

(Note: as Tommy pointed out in the comments, you would want a regex for the full password checking). If you are looking for more complex password regexes, then I suggest you look at tommy's answer and [here](http://regexlib.com/%28A%2813E-t-BjvZ-WvDNI3kEXWexqe-dnRabCLhUJT4HCwiq39cFxk1bCp2xTgMv4ZLuwh4z02qwn-LwirPbo_Y1NF6Tnx6zEJKJ9ukU7WXcOnRM1%29%29/Search.aspx?k=password&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/) to begin.

**Why (?=) doesn't work**

- `^` - match the start of the string.
- `.{8,}` - Then look forward and see if there are at least 8 characters.  (remember forward lookup doesn't change the test position so this will still be the start of the string).
- Have we reached the end ($)? No -> Fail.

Another example is that `.+(?=.{8,})$` will fail because there is no such position in the string that is followed by 8 characters and the next character from the test position is the end of string `$`.

A final example is `^.(?=.{7,})` which will match the first character of an (at least) 8 character string. This is because only the first character is preceeded by the beginning `^`

Comment: I don't think you would want a minimum length of 1 for a password.  I think what he is wanting to do is a) ensure that it is at least 8 characters and b) using regex, verify complexity of a password string such as upper case, lower case, numeric values.

Comment: @Tommy - he said that his simple regex does not enforce the minimum string length in the simple starting case. This is because his regex would not do that - he was using a forward lookup where he shouldn't.

Comment: I was more referencing your use of the `StringLength` attribute `(MinimumLength=1)` :)

Comment: Ah, yes - I mainly mentioned that as an alternative to a regex for length check. But, I take you point - I have modified. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @acarlon for the excellent explanation, I now have a much better understanding of interpreting regexes.

Comment: @DavidKnipe - I see your edit was rejected. I have included most of your changes. I was inadvertently looking a different regex (not the one from the OP in my initial description).

Comment: I'm surprised they rejected it. And I can see 2 bits that are still wrong. Your bullet point says "move to the next position", even though the regex `^(?=.{8,})$` doesn't contain anything that moves forward (matches a character) except as part of the lookahead (which is dealt with in the previous bullet point). `^$` matches the empty string, not a single-character string as you'd expect if it consumed a character at that point. And in the following paragraph, "7 characters" should be "8 characters".

Comment: @DavidKnipe - you are right on both counts - ammended. Thanks for the edits, I have upvoted one of your other answers (not sure that is by the rules, but it seems fair).

Answer (score 2):

Given that you want to verify length as well as some other password complexity rules based on your opening sentence, I recommend that you check out some of the [Regex blogs](http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/) concerning "Password Complexity Regex" on the internet.  For example, if you wanted to ensure that a password was at least 8-20 characters long and contained one upper and one lower case letter as well as a number, you would use the following regex

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,20})
```

Which basically breaks down to, I need at least 8 (no more than 20) characters, at least one must be a number, at least one must be a-z and at least one must be A-Z.  There are other examples and bits that you can put together.

For testing your regex, I would recommend a regex testing site such as http://regexhero.net/tester/.  In conjunction with the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you should be able to make some pretty nifty expressions.

Comment: Thanks very much, I now have a much, much better understanding of what these expressions mean.

Comment: @Manish - glad to help, thats why we are here.  Remember that if acarlon or my answers provided you the help you needed, to mark one as accepted (green checkmark) :)

Comment: If you read that blog entry, be sure and read [ridgerunner's comment](http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/comment-page-1/#comment-17890) concerning the leading `.*` in the author's regex. That's a very common mistake.

Comment: @AlanMoore - good point.  I wanted to provide some examples of blogs without saying "Google it", but didn't read too much into the accuracy.  Your comment did make me double check my example to ensure I didn't replicate!

Comment: Oh, good point @Tommy, I was using upticks, just marked acarlon's answer for the explanation